# Intelligent redirection

Tags: apache, http-redirect

I am a newbie using Apache 2.4.18.

I have URLs with the following form that I'd like to redirect.

```
Current URL: https://www.example.org/page/10/
Desired URL: https://www.example.org/index.php/page/10/
```

If I use the following rule, I can modify a request, eg for page 2:

```
Redirect permanent /page/2/ /index.php/page/2/
```

However, I want to redirect without having to hardcode all the pages on my site. I have tried the following, my browser fails after many redirects:

```
RedirectMatch /page/(.*)/$ /index.php/page/$1/
```

And using the following fails, I don't know why:

```
RedirectMatch "https://www.example.org/page/(.*)/$" "https://www.example.org/index.php/page/$1/"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your line

> `RedirectMatch /page/(.*)/$ /index.php/page/$1/`

`/page/2/` will in fact redirect to `/index.php/page/2/`, but this new URL will **still** match your `RedirectMatch`’s regex and will produce another redirect. That’s why it redirects endlessly until the browser gives up (see this [example](https://regex101.com/r/TjJSCD/1)).

I’d try with `RedirectMatch ^/page/(.*)/$ /index.php/page/$1/`, so when redirected, `/index.php/page/2/` will no longer match `^/page/(.*)/$` and will not produce the recursive redirects.

As an aftertought, why not use [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) instead? It’d save an additional HTTP request to the client, as redirects are usually used when you need to send the client to a different server.